# Galerkin method for existence for PDE with nonsymmetric bilinear form

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Suppose we have a PDE
$$\langle u', v \rangle + a(u,v) = 0$$
where $a:V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded symmetric bilinear form, then if $u_0 \in V$ then $u \in L^2(0,T; V)$ with $u' \in L^2(0,T;H)$. This works because we get a bound on $u_n'$ (Galerkin approximation) by writing $a(u_n, u_n')$ as $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}a(u_n, u_n)$, integrating and using the boundedness condition.

If $a$ is not symmetric (eg. $a = \int_{\Omega}\nabla \cdot (\textbf{b}u)v + \int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot \nabla v$), then we can't write it as a derivative alone. What can we do to get a uniform bound on $u_m'$ in $L^2(0,T;H)$ in this case? I know we can get a bound in $L^2(0,T;V^*)$ but I want it in a stronger space.
Thanks.

Comment: You can treat the first order term as a perturbation. If you ask it at MathStackExchange I can answer it in more detail.

Comment: @timur thanks, it's here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344230/galerkin-method-for-existence-for-pde-with-nonsymmetric-bilinear-form